# How to build boost library and others against OS X 10.4u SDK on OS X 10.6?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I'm trying to build the boost libraries and others against the os x 10.4u.sdk so I can include them in a project targeting 10.4 upwards.

I'm not entirely sure what to do, am I aiming to put the .dylibs in 10.4.sdk/usr/local/.. or in my default 10.6 /usr/local/.. with support for 10.4?

Any help much appreciated.

Toby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distribute your libraries to the users, so it doesn't help installing them into your machiine's `/usr/local`. It's better to just set the linker search path to whatever directory you have the library.

When you distribute an app, you're supposed to put every libraries you use inside the `.app` bundle (unless you're making a series of apps which share a lot of codes) so that users don't need any installer. So, there's not much to be gained by using the dynamically linked libraries, especially for non-GUI ones like boost.  So I would recommend you to make a static library `.a` and statically link against it.

If you're curious, you can find how to include frameworks in your app [here in the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482682/how-to-distribute-a-mac-os-x-with-dependent-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a mac, but here's the info i know, combined with the information i gathered on the web. The first thing to know is that most boost libraries do not require any compiled binaries. But i am guessing you know that and want to use other libraries, such as datetime or regex.

To compile boost libraries, the official way is to use a tool named bjam. Download it [there](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam/3.1.17/boost-jam-3.1.17-1-macosxx86.tgz/download) (Latest link may be found [there](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam/)).

The command line to use to compile boost libraries using bjam is shown in the [following link](http://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/d4e6a4e200e9e578?pli=1).

```
bjam --toolset=darwin --build-type=complete --with-thread 
    --with-date_time --with-filesystem 
    --with-regex --with-system architecture=combined
```

UNTESTED (by me), but all the sources i found suggest this is the right approach.